# definition of sinusoidal curve

Tags: geometry, plane-curves, rotations, polar-coordinates

I have question related with  these two definition:
In geometry, the sinusoidal spirals are a family of curves defined by the equation in polar coordinates

$$r^n = a^n \cos(n \theta)$$

where $a$ is a nonzero constant and $n$ is a rational number other than $0$.
On the other hand, with a rotation about the origin, this can also be written

$$r^n = a^n \sin(n \theta)$$

Why so different? Rotation about the origin does create in some situation  cosine and sine function same or? Please explain to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sinusoid is a function which can be written in the form $f(x) = R\sin (ax + b)$. So for example $\cos x = \sin (-x + \frac{\pi}{2})$, and so forth.

It sounds like your sinusoidal spiral is a generalisation of this: [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinusoidal_spiral) has more information.